# How to call updated hook after axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

In updated hook, I call a method, that store data via action:

**hook updated:**

```
updated() {
  this.storeOptions()
},
```

method:

```
storeOptions() {
    this.$store.dispatch("storeFilters", {
      idCategory: this.idCategory,
      genres: this.genres,
      priceFrom: this.optionsSlider.value[0],
      priceTo: this.optionsSlider.value[1],
      place: this.activePlace.id,
      count: 6
    });
  }
```

The problem is that now hook 'updated' is called immediately after the render of the component and 2 more times (get the slider options once and again, get the drop-down list options). This is not optimized...

I tried something like that

```
updated() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.storeOptions()
  })
},
```

But it did not help...

axios call in mounted hook

```
mounted() {
  axios
    .get(
      `/api/categories/filterParams.php?categoryId=${
        this.idCategory}`
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.categories = response.data;
      this.optionsSlider.min = +this.categories.minPrice;
      this.optionsSlider.max = +this.categories.maxPrice;
      this.optionsSlider.value = [
        this.optionsSlider.min,
        this.optionsSlider.max
      ];
      this.filterPlacesCategory();
    });
},
```

Comment: Where is the `axios` portion of the code?

Comment: @RuChernChong Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of blanket calling `this.storeOptions()` on the update hook. You could call it in the `then` of the `axios` call, and also hook it into any other necessary event that would benefit from the call, eg) `@click` or `@input` on any inputs you have.